# Generate non consecutive random numbers within a range

Tags: php, random

I have the following code

```
<?php
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $tmp = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    //sort($tmp);
    return $tmp;
}
echo '<pre>';
$arr = randomGen(2,7,5);
//sort($arr);}
print_r($arr);
```

This code generates random n numbers between the specified range.

However, it returns the output similar to the following many times

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 2
)
```

Here, 2 3 4 5 are consecutive numbers. **I am trying to modify the above code so that it does not return more than 3 consecutive numbers.** The output should be similar to this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
)
```

As you can see, it has just 3 consecutive numbers 5 6 7.

I have tried the following

```
<?php

function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    $tmp = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    sort($tmp);
    return $tmp;
}
echo '<pre>';
$arr = randomGen(2,7,5);
$count = 0;
$first = $arr[0];
$i = 1;
//for($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
while ($i < count($arr)) {
    $ele = $arr[$i];
    if ($counter >=3) {
        $counter = 0;
        $arr = randomGen(2,7,5);
        $first = $arr[0];
        $i = 1;
    }
    else {
    if ($ele - $first === 1) {
        $counter++;

        //continue;
    }

    $first = $ele;
}
$i++;
}
print_r($arr);
```

But it doesn't provide the expected output.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: there can be unique number in the list ?

Comment: Yes numbers have to be unique

Comment: please have a look at the answer below

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another approach. Each time you generate a number... just remove its previous and next number as options. This will ensure no 2 consecutive numbers appear... and obviously no 3 (you can adapt to allow 2 by adding like 1 condition and checking after each generation).

```
<?php

$numbers = range(0, 100);
$quantity = 40;
$result = [];

if ($quantity > count($numbers) / 2 - 1) {
    throw new Exception('Impossible');
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++) {
    $rnd = rand(0, count($numbers) -1);
    $tmp = $numbers[$rnd];
    $result[] = $tmp;
    unset($numbers[$rnd]);
    
    foreach ($numbers as $key => $number) {
        if (abs($number - $tmp) <= 1) {
            unset($numbers[$key]);
        }
    }
    
    $numbers = array_values($numbers);
}

var_dump($result);
```

P.S. That goes inside the function and remove the hardcoded things I used to test the code (0, 100 and 40) :).

Answer (score 0):

Please see if we can do something like this

```
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity,$rangestep) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max,$rangestep);

    $tmp = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
    sort($tmp);
    shuffle($tmp);
    return $tmp;
}
echo '<pre>';
$arr = randomGen(2,7,5,1);
$count = 0;
$first = $arr[0];
$i = 1;
//for($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
$counter = 0;
while ($i < count($arr)) {
  $ele = $arr[$i];
  if ($counter >=3) {
    $counter = 0;
    $arr = randomGen(2,7,8,2);
    $first = $arr[0];
    $i = 1;
  }
   else {
   if ($ele - $first === 1) {
      $counter++;

      //continue;
   }
  $first = $ele;
  }
 $i++;
 } 
  print_r($arr);
 die;
```

Comment: Getting the following a couple of times
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
)
Here, 4 5 6 7 is consecutive

Comment: Okay it’s failed in 2 out of 10 attempts

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please have a look if it has solved your problem

Comment: All 5 numbers were consecutive in first 3 attempts